# Algebraic Proof Help

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am attempting to prove that $(C-A) ∩ (∩)=∅$ algebraically but I keep getting stuck. 
Here is my attempt:

$(C-A) ∩ (∩)$

$(C ∩ A^c) ∩ (A ∩ B)$

$C ∩ (A^c ∩ (A ∩ B))$

$C ∩ ((A ∩ B) ∩ A^c)$

$C ∩ ( (A ∩ B) -C)$

Comment: What is $A \cap A^C$?

Comment: From your third line to your fourth line, do $A^c \cap A$ instead.

Comment: That would make the empty set but how am I allowed to say that?

Answer (score 0):

In the last line you should have

$C\cap((A\cap B)-A)$

and since $A\cap B\subseteq A$, you should be able to finish.

On the other hand, $A^c\cap(A\cap B)=(A^c\cap A)\cap B=\emptyset\cap B$, which is easier.

Comment: Thank you so much